# Pandas: agg() gives me 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to `agg()` a df at the same time I make a subsetting from one of the columns:

```
indi = pd.DataFrame({"PONDERA":[1,2,3,4], "ESTADO": [1,1,2,2]})

empleo = indi.agg(ocupados = (indi.PONDERA[indi["ESTADO"]==1], sum) )
```

but I'm getting `'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`

I want to sum the values of "PONDERA" only when "ESTADO" == 1.

Expected output:

```
  ocupados
0     3
```

I'm trying to imitate R function `summarise()`, so I want to do it in one step **and agg some other columns too**.

In R would be something like:

```
empleo <- indi %>% 
  summarise(poblacion = sum(PONDERA),
            ocupados = sum(PONDERA[ESTADO == 1]))
```

Is this even the correct approach?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: can you please post a sample df, and the expected output

Answer (score 1):

Generally `agg` takes as an argument function, not Series itself. In your case though it's more beneficial to separate filtering and summation.

One of the options would be the following:

```py
empleo = indi.query("ESTADO == 1")[["PONDERA"]].sum()
```

(Use single square brackets to output single number, instead of `pd.Series`)

Comment: thanks for the answer. The real issue is that I want to make some other aggs (with their respective new column names) in the same df, like summarise() in R does. eg: `empleo = indi.agg(poblacion = ("PONDERA", sum), ocupados = (indi.loc[indi.ESTADO == 1, "PONDERA"], sum)) `

Comment: Then replace `.sum()` in my query with `.agg({"<col_name>": ["sum", "avg"], "<col2_name>": "sum"})` if you want to do sum if + sum you should rather split it by adding new column with 0-ed cells, not matching the condition (try `numpy.where(..)`). You would need to clarify your question, not using r example but what exactly you want to obtain - now it requires r-knowledge, which I personally don't have...

Comment: ok, I undestand. I'm guessing there is no way to simplify it as creating a column and applying a sum if at the same operation (like agg() does without logical subseting). sorry about the R example, it's a really much more easier operation there and i'm trying to compare and document differences, so everything helps. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are two different ways you can get the scalar value 3.

```
option1 = indi.loc[indi['ESTADO'].eq(1),'PONDERA'].sum()
option2 = indi['PONDERA'].where(indi['ESTADO'].eq(1)).sum()
```

However, your expected output shows this value in a dataframe. To do this, you can create a new dataframe with the desired column name "ocupados".

```
outputdf = pd.DataFrame({'ocupados':[option1]})
```

Based on your comment you provided, is this what you are looking for?

```
(indi.agg(poblacion = ("PONDERA", 'sum'),
          ocupados = ('PONDERA',lambda x: x.where(indi['ESTADO'].eq(1)).sum())))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @rhug123 . The real issue is that I want to make some other aggs (with their respective new column names) in the same df, like summarise() in R does. eg: `empleo = indi.agg(poblacion = ("PONDERA", sum), ocupados = (indi.loc[indi.ESTADO == 1, "PONDERA"], sum)) `

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use `loc` and filter the dataframe to when estado = 1, and `sum` the values of the column pondera:

```
indi.loc[indi.ESTADO==1, ['PONDERA']].sum()
```

Thanks to @Henry's input.

Comment: Chained expressions should be avoided, use: `indi.loc[indi.ESTADO==1, ['PONDERA']].sum()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Could you elaborate a bit more about why chained expressions should be avoided?

Comment: `indi.loc[indi.ESTADO==1]` creates a copy of the DataFrame, then you select column from the copy with `[['PONDERA']]`. (1) it's a bad habit because it only works with getting not setting, `indi.loc[indi.ESTADO==1][['PONDERA']] = 1` for example will raise a SettingWithCopyWarning and `indi` will not be modified because you will be modifying the copy created by `indi.loc[indi.ESTADO==1]` (not the original DataFrame `indi`), and (2) it takes significantly more time and memory to slice the DataFrame twice and generate 2 copies than slicing once and making 1 copy.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain, appreciated.

Comment: thanks for the answer @sophocles @Henry . The real issue is that I want to make some other aggs (with their respective new column names) in the same df, like summarise() in R does. eg: `empleo = indi.agg(poblacion = ("PONDERA", sum), ocupados = (indi.loc[indi.ESTADO == 1, "PONDERA"], sum)) `

Answer (score 0):

A bit fancy, but the output is exactly the format you want, and the syntax is similar to what you tried:

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) instead of [`DataFrame.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html):

```
empleo = (indi.loc[indi['ESTADO']==1]
              .groupby('ESTADO')
              .agg(ocupados=('PONDERA', sum))
              .reset_index(drop=True)
         )
```

**Result:**

`print(empleo)` gives:

```
   ocupados
0         3
```